# Case expression not working as expected with 'on duplicate key update' clause

Tags: mysql, sql, on-duplicate-key, case-expression

Through the following query, I want to update the `ConcurrentJobs` column only when the value in `MaxConcurrentJobs` column is `greater than or equal to` the value of `ConcurrentJobs` being updated.

```
insert into userjobinfo (UserId,ConcurrentJobs) values (335,2300)
            on duplicate key update ConcurrentJobs = case when values(MaxConcurrentJobs) >= ConcurrentJobs
                                    then ConcurrentJobs else values(ConcurrentJobs) end;
```

But the above query doesn't work as expected. It always updates the value `2300` in the `concurrent jobs` column even if the condition fails. What could be the reason for this? Where does the query fail?

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: @jarlh Edited..

Answer (score 0):

> ..VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the
>   value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key
>   conflict occurred. The VALUES() function is meaningful only in INSERT
>   ... UPDATE statements and returns NULL otherwise
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Since `values(MaxConcurrentJobs)` refers to a column you are NOT inserting it is NULL so your condition always defaults to  `values(ConcurrentJobs)`.Use a trigger for that logic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refer columns already in the row using `VALUES()`; that is for the *new* values in supplied by the `INSERT`.  I think the following should work:

```
insert into userjobinfo (UserId,ConcurrentJobs)
    values (335, 2300)
    on duplicate key update
        ConcurrentJobs = (case when MaxConcurrentJobs >= VALUES(ConcurrentJobs)
                               then VALUES(ConcurrentJobs)
                               else ConcurrentJobs
                          end);
```